# Question about a sentence on Griffiths QM book about the free electron gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, electrons

In line six and page 220 of the book (http://boltz.ccne.ufsm.br/pub/rsauer/estmat/2017/griffiths.pdf), it is stated that ''each intersection point represents a distinct (one-particle) stationary state''.

My question is, why are the intersections in the grid that represent the particles?

Comment: What is it specifically about that statement that bothers you?

Comment: I dont understand why each intersection is considered a particle.

Comment: Each intersection is a one-particle _state_, that may or may not be occupied by a particle.

Comment: Why the middle of the box isnt considered a particle or, say, other point near the intersection point?

Comment: The wavefunction must be zero at the edges of the box. This means that momentum is restricted to discrete values.

Comment: I can't seem to find a link between your argument and the implication of a particle in the intersection yet.

Comment: The only possible states are those with specific momenta. The momenta of these possible states form a lattice in momentum space. They do not represent particles, but rather possible states that a particle could occupy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, this is not a box in position space, but in *momentum space*. That is, each intersection corresponds to a particular $n_x$, $n_y$, and $n_z$, not to a real physical position. The stationary states of a 3-D particle in a box can be separated into 3 stationary states in $x$, $y$, and $z$, and so is discrete just like the 1-D problems.

Comment: That helps. So, I know what a stationary state is, but why is it ''correct'' to consider the stationary states as particles?

Comment: Isnt there the probability that the particle could be in other part of the box?

Comment: The book doesn't say that. It says each intersection is a stationary state. These stationary states may or may not be occupied. Without thermal excitation, however, what you end up with is the global ground state occupied- which gives all those states below a certain energy being occupied and all those above unoccupied.